# What's the proof for the #integers less than $n$ that can be expressed as the sum of two squares is $\frac n{\sqrt{\log n}}$?

Tags: number-theory

This result is used in the Erdos' Distance problem, in the Landau-Ramanujan constant, but I can't find a proof anywhere.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_distinct_distances_problem
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Ramanujan_constant

Comment: You mean: "of order" that?

Comment: Already asked (and answered in a comment) on the site [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/462416/).

Comment: Yea, sorry, I meant Big O. And could somebody sketch out a proof; I don't have access to the book anywhere atm. Much appreciated.

Comment: You may find some usefuil links at https://oeis.org/A001481